# Anylogic: Running a model but stuck suddenly without any error

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I'm new to Anylogic and created a simple traffic model. Only use 'carSource', 'CarMoveTo', 'Car Dispose' blocks to set the car routes. But After I ran the model, it worked for a while, then all the cars froze without any error occurring. ’Events‘ panel also stopped. How to solve it?

[image: Developer Panel]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your model is running into an infinite loop somewhere in the logic. The first place to check would be all your loops that might become infinite,e.g Do loops, Do-while loops, iterator for loops where you perhaps change the counter variable manually...

If you have the professional version of AnyLogic the best option is to run the model in debug mode until you get this to the point where it freezes and then press pause. You will then see where in the code the model is getting stuck.

[image]

If this does not work you might need to start putting traceln in major functions and see ing you can spot the last traceln that gets printed and keep on adding more and more until you can find the point between two traceln where the model freezes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, that after a certain time, all cars froze and there wasn't a signle error.

The problem on my side was that the **stop line** was too **close to the intersection**, so I moved it a **little bit farther**.